# Can't connect to network in Windows 7, but can in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I just got an internet connection at home with a wireless router. 
For some reason, I cannot connect to this network on Windows 7. My phone (samsung corby pro) can connect to it and I can surf. I can even connect to the network in Ubuntu and everything works. My roommate has no issues connecting to the network.

My guess is that the wireless drivers on windows 7 are not up to date. Windows update doesn't offer any newer drivers, and the manufacturer's website doesn't list any drivers for windows 7 at all.

My laptop is a HP dv6750ee, which has a Atheros AR5007 802.11b/g Wifi Adapter (got that from device manager).

I connect and use other wireless networks on a daily basis from windows 7, and nothing seems to be wrong.

I think there is some problem with the network authentication used and supported by my current driver in windows 7. Can anyone point out the solution?

Comment: I know this is old but if it is still a problem it'd probably be nice for you to have it fixed... What security settings do you have set on your router (WPA/WEP/...) If you turn off any security are you able to connect to it? Dose you even see it in the list of available connections?

Answer (score 0):

Can you even see the SSID of the Wireless Network in Windows? If yes then try to put Static IP on Windows to see if that solves the problem. Tell your roommate to see what IP his laptop gets and then add 1 at the last number of the IP and put this information into your Windows 7 system.

For example:

```
Ubuntu
IP        192.168.0.31
Mask      255.255.255.0
Gateway   192.168.0.254
DNS       192.168.0.254
```

You will give your Windows 7 information:

```
IP        192.168.0.32
Mask      255.255.255.0
Gateway   192.168.0.254
DNS       192.168.0.254
```